# how to keep only application related logs and remove all other Function related logs

Tags: azure-functions, serilog-sinks-file

I an using Serilog with Azure Function app and all possible extra logs I set level either with warning or error,

```
 var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Worker", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Host", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Host.Aggregator", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Host.Results", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Error)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Function", LogEventLevel.Error)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Azure.Storage.Blobs", LogEventLevel.Error)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Azure.Core", LogEventLevel.Error)
```

This certainly minimize the logs data, but still I am seeing logs line which I don't want. I want only the application functionalities logs (`2022-07-06 03:53:08.821 +00:00 [INF]  my-test-SessionId=Order-5;Message:Message-0`)

Is there any other settings I am missing? Thanks.

```
2022-07-06 03:53:08.816 +00:00 [INF]  my-queue-6b96259f-cb54-4ac7-9b20-2e4a695c539e: ReceiveBatchAsync start. MessageCount = 1

2022-07-06 03:53:08.819 +00:00 [INF]  my-queue-6b96259f-cb54-4ac7-9b20-2e4a695c539e: ReceiveBatchAsync done. Received '1' messages. LockTokens = <LockToken>05dc6848-50ea-4e81-afdd-62a838c0b4a9</LockToken>

2022-07-06 03:53:08.819 +00:00 [INF]  my-queue-e4de37f9-9b92-401a-8b9c-1212bc85011d: User message handler start: Message: SequenceNumber: 50275, LockToken: 05dc6848-50ea-4e81-afdd-62a838c0b4a9

2022-07-06 03:53:08.821 +00:00 [INF]  my-test-SessionId=Order-5;Message:Message-0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you need to add `Azure.Storage.Queues` as an override.
In my case, I'm also using durable functions, which requires adding an override for `DurableTask`.

Comment: Thanks. It's a service bus and I added like and it's works `.MinimumLevel.Override("Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus", LogEventLevel.Error)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs", LogEventLevel.Error)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus", LogEventLevel.Error)`

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it working. Your post helped me to get my case covered, so thanks!